# How do I mock axios.defaults when using Enyme/Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I have a component with the following...

```
export class Mine extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

I am trying to write a test but I get the following...

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'withCredentials' of undefined

I tried the following in the test class...

```
import axios from "axios";
jest.mock("axios"); 
...
// Tried this...
axios.defaults = {}
// And this...
axios.Prototype.defaults = {}
```

But nothing seems to work. Is this a setter I need to mock or something?

Comment: please show your test file full code. I want to see how you mocked axios

Comment: @LidorAvitan I have included all the lines of code I used to mock axios I did try adding jest.mock("axios"); but it didn't help either. Added to the code example in case it is interesting :-)

Comment: @DanielLizik Already looked there and doesn't provide info I need unless you want to reference an individual part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the below code. Here we are trying to mock axios and returning the mock object with defaults as its property:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  defaults: { withCredentials: true }
}));
```

Comment: This is great now how would I add a mocked out post function that I can change the response. I will create another question but I get can't access outside variable errors